# Pylint in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pylint, pyproject.toml

I am able to run `find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint` just fine on the command line. However, when it is run in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline, the pyproject.toml doesn't seem to matter, as it is trying to run it on the files in test.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - linting
pylint:
  stage: linting
  image: registry.gitlab.com/mafda/python-linting
  script: 
    - find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs pylint
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

pyproject.toml

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 119

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"

[tool.pylint.message_control]
max-line-length = 119
disable = ["import-error"]
ignore-paths = [
  "test/*",
]

[tool.pylint.BASIC]
good-names = ["X", "*X", "y"]

[tool.pylint.DESIGN]
max-attributes=12
max-args=6
```

Output from command line:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

Output from GitLab CI/CD:

```
************* Module test_datasets_utils
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:15:0: C0115: Missing class docstring (missing-class-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:16:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:16:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:22:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:22:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:28:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:28:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:38:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:38:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:48:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:48:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:57:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:57:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:64:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/test_datasets_utils.py:64:4: R0201: Method could be a function (no-self-use)
************* Module conftest
tests/conftest.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
tests/conftest.py:6:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
************* Module stock_data
tests/fixtures/stock_data.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
tests/fixtures/stock_data.py:80:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/fixtures/stock_data.py:93:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
tests/fixtures/stock_data.py:106:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
-----------------------------------
```

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: In `pyproject.toml` you are telling `pylint` to ignore the `test` directory, but the output from the GitLab CI/CD indicates your tests are in the `tests` directory. But this doesn't explain why you are getting different outputs from  the local execution vs on the Gitlab runner.